# App is not updating database when string contains spaces

Tags: mysql, ios, database, contacts, space

I ran into a weird problem. I built a mysql database where the user can store his contacts through an app. He just adds his contact information by clicking on a button. Then, the data is added to the database.

However, when the contact's information has spaces between his first name, last name or number the app refuses to accept the data. I dont get an error message or anything like that, but I also dont get any confirmation. The record does not exist in the database.

There is no problem with my php file (The file is definitely correct, I got it checked here, twice). 
Here is my code:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/phpFile.php?number=%@&name=%@&lastname=%@", number, firstName, lastName];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

Comment: Please don't anthropomorphize your code. It makes it difficult for some people to follow.

Comment: Are you using Core Data? Maybe one of the entities attributes type is not set correctly.

Comment: @Paul: Sorry, english is not my native tongue and I get carried away sometimes, I will edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space character is not allowed in a URI.  Use %20 to encode the space.  There are other characters that are also not allowed as part of the URI.  Look up URI encoding.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the same thing. But I have no idea where I could put it in my code, because I can't know where the spaces will be when someone uses the app.

Comment: Look at the following link for how to encode: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140424/stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-not-working-with-nsstrings-with-0)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/phpFile.php?number=%@&name=%@&lastname=%@", number, firstName, lastName];
strURL  = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```