# How to encode URL in objective c xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, url, encode

I'm doing this to encode my URL in this way,
but its not working,
i got the result in NSLog but its the same url nothing is changing.

Please help me to sort this issue.

below is my code :

```
 NSString *unencodedUrlString = 

[@"http://www.demii.com/demo/dooponz/admin/index.php/chat/new_message/4/1/you/2,7" 

stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@" %@", unencodedUrlString);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: so actually what do you expect as output?

Comment: @LithuT.V
i expect this output:- http://www.demii.com/demo/dooponz/admin/index.php/chat/new_message/4/1/you/2%2C7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140424/stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-not-working-with-nsstrings-with-0  ;   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html  Seems to me that you understand the purpose of *stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding* in a wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.demii.com/demo/dooponz/admin/index.php/chat/new_message/4/1/you/2,7"];
    NSString *path = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"/"];
    NSLog(@"%@",path);
```

This will do nothing but will make `,` to `/`.

Comment: Thanks its finally working and i finally understand and thanks to Vin as well

Answer (score 2):

The comma is a legal URL character, therefore `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` leaves "2,7" as it is and does not replace it by "2%2C7".

If you want the comma to be replaced by a percent escape (as I understand from your
comment to the question), you can use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`
instead:

```
NSString *str = @"http://www.demii.com/demo/dooponz/admin/index.php/chat/new_message/4/1/you/2,7";
NSString *encoded = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                (__bridge CFStringRef)(str), NULL, CFSTR(","), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
NSLog(@"%@", encoded);
```

Output:

```
http://www.demii.com/demo/dooponz/admin/index.php/chat/new_message/4/1/you/2%2C7
```

The fourth parameter `CFSTR(",")` specifies that the comma should be replaced by
a percent escape even if it is a legal URL character.