# stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding error string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I'm sending a `GET` request and my url is

```
http://myurl.com/addpla?name=JJ Burger &category=Delicatessen and Other &location=Sao jose do Rio Preto
```

(I did use `NSLog` and it's correct)

but after

```
NSString *encodedURL = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

the url is:

```
http://myurl.com/addpla?name=JJ2urger0X1.8A1301528AP-685&category=Delicatessen0x1.8ac90146a39e1p-698nd2427076260ther0X1.442030000206P-1018&location=Sao1455040047316337024se0o2io¢e
```

Comment: Please reformat your question, it is barely readable. In particular, use four spaces before your urls and not quotes blocks (`>`).

Comment: Using exactly the same code I get: `http://myurl.com/addpla?name=JJ%20Burger%20&category=Delicatessen%20and%20Other%20&location=Sao%20jose%20do%20Rio%20Preto` which of course is correct...

Comment: How are you determining that this is the value of `encodedURL`? Might you be making the same `NSLog` mistake as [the poster in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3141340/371228)?

Comment: I determine because I use NSLog

Comment: @bdesham is probably right. Can you post your `NSLog` statement as well ?

Comment: NSString *encodedURL = [urlPlace stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(encodedURL);

Comment: Kudos to @bdesham for guessing correctly! Should we close as a duplicate?